# Erro na Leitura Arquivos XML Bovespa com R

Tags: r, xml

Tentei utilizar todas as bibliotecas para manipulação de *XML* disponíveis no `R` que encontrei, porém não consegui, com nenhuma delas, realizar a leitura dos novos arquivos de cotação de fechamento disponibilizados pela *Bovespa*(atual B3) em seu site, no [link](http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/historico/boletins-diarios/pesquisa-por-pregao/pesquisa-por-pregao/), arquivo `BVBG.086.01 PriceReport`.

Não sei se devo realizar alguma modificação nestes arquivos preliminarmente, mas o fato é que o `R` não reconhece estes arquivos *XML* como *XML*, e precisaria muito conseguir manipular estes dados dentro da ferramenta em meu trabalho.

Desde já lhes agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui ler os dados sem problemas utilizando o pacote `xml`:

```
library(XML)

# primeiro arquivo
b3 <- xmlTreeParse(file = "BVBG.086.01_BV000328201901310328000001834044379.xml")

# segundo arquivo
b3 <- xmlTreeParse(file = "BVBG.086.01_BV000328201901310328000001859152868.xml")

# terceiro arquivo
b3 <- xmlTreeParse(file = "BVBG.086.01_BV000328201901310328000001933430443.xml")
```

Comment: Olá Marcus

Desculpe, sou bem novo na programação em R. Utilizando o xmlParse não estava funcionando, e com o xmlTreeParse a leitura do arquivo ocorreu bem, apesar de o arquivo ficar bem grande com 1,3Gb aqui).

Consegue me dar uma ajuda em como obter os dados abaixo em um dataframe? Basicamente são o código do ativo, preço de negócio e volume negociado (máximo, mínimo, etc)

Apesar de muito ter lido nestes últimos dias, não consegui nenhum avanço.
<TckrSymb>PETR4T</TckrSymb>
Desde já lhe agradeço muito